# How to distinguish between unavoidable obligations and strong recommendations?

Tags: grammar

In English, *have to* is used for strong obligations. For example, I have the obligation (by the rules of the house) to study when my mother says "You have to study". See [here](https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar-vocabulary/grammar-videos/have-must-and-should-obligation-and-advice) for example.

On the other hand, *should* is used for recommendations and strong advice. If I say "You should study" to a friend, I mean that he will have troubles if he don't do it, but it is implied that it is ultimately his choice.

The difference is small and my textbook translates both sentences by 공부 해야 돼요.

Is there a grammatical structure that I can use to introduce the nuance between *have to* and *should*?

Comment: I thought that the urgency is ordered as "must > should > have to > need to". Was I understanding incorrectly?

Comment: Related question on [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123937/what-is-the-difference-between-have-to-must-and-should). Can you include some context (a dialogue) where you need to use "have to" or "should"? Your question is unanswerable without any context and it is too broad.

Comment: @Hwang: I am not sure there is a linear order (you said you are into maths ;) ?) between them but subtle nuances. One reference I read before asking the question is https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar-vocabulary/grammar-videos/have-must-and-should-obligation-and-advice

Comment: @Rathony: Dialogue, seriously? In which way my examples lack context? Isn't "I have the obligation (by the rules of the house)" enough context?

Comment: Although “have to” and “should” have many meanings, I think the question body here is clear about which particular usages are being referred to. I wonder if the title itself might be clearer if it didn't focus so much on those particular words though? Something like "How to distinguish between unavoidable obligations and strong recommendations"? Just a thought.

Comment: @topomorto: This seems to be a reasonable change.

Comment: Thanks. What I learned from school was not correct. Anyway, by the fact that I have a trouble understanding the difference, you may be convinced that there is no distinction in Korean, unless you use words like obligations or recommendations explicitly.

Comment: @Hwang: the difference is very tiny. For example, should can be used to express unavoidable obligations in a polite way, without giving the impression to give orders. That's why I changed the title.

Comment: @Taladris I don't think you understand what I requested. This is not a discussion forum. You should quote one or two specific examples in English or Korean and ask about their difference. That's the way any language site on SE works. You are asking as if all the users including myself would know what "unavoidable obligation" and "strong recommendation" mean. What do they mean? What are they? What can't you avoid? What are you recommending strongly? Do you think the Korean language is so simple that it has one expression for each? We discussed the issue of your question broad. Why? No context

Comment: 공부해야 돼요. 공부해야 해요. 공부안하면 안 돼요. 공부하지 않으면 안 돼요. 공부해야 할 거예요. 꼭 공부 해야 해요. 꼭 공부 해야 돼요. 반드시 공부 해야 해요. 반드시 공부 해야 돼요. 절대로 공부 해야 해요. 절대로 공부 해야 돼요. 어떤 일이 있어도 공부 해야 돼요. 어떤 일이 있어도 공부 해야 해요. 틀림없이 공부 해야 해요. 틀림없이 공부 해야 돼요. 조금도 어김 없이 공부 해야 해요. 조금도 어김 없이 공부 해야 돼요. 공부 할 수 밖에 없어요. 공부 안 하면 죽어요. 공부 하지 않을 수 없어요., etc. All of these mean "I should / have to study". Can you see how broad your question is? You should note that not many native Korean would say 공부를 할 필요가 있다. or 공부를 할 필요가 있어요 when you have to say "should" or "have to". They sound weird. Your question is too broad and that's why such an answer is posted.

Comment: @Rathony Why can't we add 조금도 before 틀림없이 but ok when before 어김없이? I'm a bit puzzled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Korean, both "should" and "have to" are expressed by the same grammatical structure: 아/어야 되다/하다/지(colloquial)/겠다(future tense equivalent). Koreans do not identify the difference between "have to" and "should" in their daily life as they are conveying very similar meaning. The only difference of these two words in English is the extent.

If you want, you may also use another grammar: ㄹ/을 필요가 있다. But its correct translation should be "need to".

Example: 숙제를 오늘밤에 할 필요가 있다. -> You need to finish your homework tonight.(changing "need to" to "have to" does not seem to make a difference in this case)

ㄹ/을 수밖에 없다 could be similar, but its meaning should be "can only".

Example: 이 곳에서 떠날 수밖에 없어요. -> I can only leave this place. (I have to leave this place.)

*Addressing the expression "You are recommended to...":*

I think using (으)면 좋(겠)다 will best fit the meaning. Ex: 지금부터 공부하면 좋겠어.

If you want to express the word "strongly", you may use 강하게, or I saw 강력히 being used in articles. But combining it with the grammatical principle quoted above may not be a good idea. You may use the word 권하다, but it is a bit authoritative.

Ex: You are strongly recommended to think twice. 
다시 생각해 보는 것을 강력히 권합니다.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that your answer addresses only the case of "have to" (unavoidable obligation). What about a strong recommendation like should? In that case, in English, it is also possible to say "You are strongly recommended to study", though it sounds very formal. I would accept your answer if you add that bit.

Comment: Could '하면 좋다' be used in a translation of 'should' as a strong recommendation? Or can it not be strong enough?

Comment: Examples(strong recommendation): 길 건널 때에는 조심해야한다.(You should be careful when you cross the street.) 공부는 도서관에서 해야돼.(The place where you study should be a library.) 칼을 뽑았으면 무라도 베어야지.(Once you draw the sword, you should at least cut a radish.)